# How can I modify this code to include the parent?

Tags: templates

I use the code below to show site pages and template.

I'd like to know how to modify it to show any parents before the post_title.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT post_title, meta_value
FROM $wpdb->posts a
JOIN $wpdb->postmeta b ON a.ID = b.post_id
WHERE a.post_type = 'page'
AND a.post_status = 'publish'
AND b.meta_key = '_wp_page_template'
";

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
if( !empty( $results ) ) {
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $results as $result ) {
echo '<li>'. $result->post_title . ': ' . $result->meta_value. '</li>';}
echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Or, if there's an alternative way of getting parent:page:template.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do that and WordPress has some default functions to get that parent page. In fact there is a thing called `post_parent` in `post` object. However, you can use the below techniques I think-

1. `get_post_ancestors( $post )` function. Here `$post` is ID or object. [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors) you'll find the documentation.
2. You can also use `wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID )`. [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_parent_id) you'll find the documentation.
3. You can also do that by getting the `post_parent` like
   `$post->post_parent`. Then use `get_post()` or any other function to get that page variable name.

Hope that thing helps.